# Django - templatedoesnotexist

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a project named "crepes_bretonnes". In this project, I have an application blog. I created a template date.html. Here is the structure of my folders :

```
crepes_bretonnes/
    blog/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        templates/
            blog/
                addition.html
                date.html
        tests.py
        views.py
    crepes_bretonnes/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    templates/
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

When I try to see the page, I have a message templateDoesNotExist. I have read a lot about it on the web but I have not succeed in resolving my problem. In fact, I don't understand why Django does not search in my template folder of the app blog although I wrote "blog" in `INSTALLED_APP` in setting.py. Obviously, I have put `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)` in `setting.py`. I also tried to change the dictionary TEMPLATES. However, if I have understood well, it has no link as here Django should find my template even without this.
I don't have any solution.

Thank you for your help.

PS: If I put date.html in the general template folder and I arrange some lines, it works. However that is not a solution, I would like to respect a good structure.

**UPDATE**:

Thank you for your answer. Yes it really says `INSTALLED_APPS` in my setting and `APP_DIRS` is already `True`.

Here is my `TEMPLATES` in `setting.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**UPDATE**:
The debug message shows that Django search in django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/benjamin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/date.html.
However I have not written anything in these folder ... I'm working in Documents. Why does Django search here and not in Documents ?

Comment: Apparently it is not exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem saying template does not exist and I solved it by changing the URL pattern in my views.py where previously I had mentioned just date.html, later I edited with blog/date.html. Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding forward slash "/" after 'templates':

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates/'],
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `'INSTALLED_APP'` is a typo and it really says `'INSTALLED_APPS'` in your settings. Anyway, you need to set `APP_DIRS = True` for templates to be found in `app/templates`
 folders:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,  # this line is important
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
                # ...
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it really says 'INSTALLED_APPS' in my setting and 'APP_DIRS' is already True.

Here is my "TEMPLATES" in setting.py :

Answer (score 1):

me having the same issue,
added the app to the INSTALLED_APPS
done, because you (and me) were using the templates not in the main app so it must be registered in the settings (like referring to the urls of the app from the main urls file)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your setting.py and try something like:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
```

For example:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using rest_framework without adding it to INSTALLED_APPS.